# What does the residual plot of a model against a term not in the model mean?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Let's say I have a linear regression model $Y = \beta_0+\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2X_2$.

I know that plotting the residuals against $X_1$, for example, will show that the model is a good fit if the residuals are randomly scattered.

But what if I took the residuals from that model and plot them against $X_1^2$, the quadratic term? If it looks nonrandom, does this mean that the quadratic term would be helpful to add to the model?

Comment: In multiple regression it is customary to plot 'residuals` against 'fits' (instead of, or in addition to plots against  $X_1, S_2,$ etc.).One looks for non-random patterns, trends, and 'fanning out' (variance or resids increasing as fits increase)--all of which may be evidence that model assumptions might be met. // In simple regression a plot of residuals against $X$ and a plot of residuals against fits will look the same (even though the horizontal scale is different).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, it may point that you have a heteroscedasticity. Namely, a non equal variance. Actually, [White's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_test) for detecting non-equal variance is based exactly on this idea.